# Files used for storage in ssas cube

Tags: ssas

Can any one tell me about the structure of the file (like 8kb file in database for storing data) used for storing data in ssas cube.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you want to know how does SSAS stores data internally?

you should start by understanding how SSAS stores data at all...

Do you understand the 3 storage modes? ROLAP, HOLAP and MOLAP? If you have ROLAP you actually dont have fact data on your cube, it is 100% on your relational database and if you have HOLAP you only have aggregations.

You should also understand how partitioning works. Basically you can "cut" your fact data into several pieces based on a condition (usually a date) and store different places

Comment: Hi, Thank You for reply.I know some basics about ROLAP,HOLAP,etc.I want to know about the kind of files ssas is using for storing data for these ROLAP,HOLAP,MOLAP methods.(For example in normal sql database we know .mdf file and this file is logicaly divided into 8kb files,their the data is storing in row wise..)